# Does the ISS medical inventory include a sun-tan/sunscreen lotion/cream?

Tags: iss, radiation, health

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_threat_from_cosmic_rays) writes to say

> Exposures on the ISS average 150 mSv per year, although frequent crew rotations minimize individual risk

I assume here the crew aboard the space-station receive more radiation during their stint than they would on Terra Firma over a year.

Random synapses firing ...

- As compared to UV exposure on Earth' surface, how much more UV does a crew-member aboard ISS receive during the typical course of an expedition?
- If the answer to the above is noticeably larger, would it translate to a visible tan on crew at debark as compared to the same crew at embarkation?

  - What about non-ISS expeditions?
- Does the ISS medical inventory include a sun-tan/sunscreen lotion/cream?

  - How much of it is ferried in a typical resupply mission?

Comment: No- there's no sunblock in either Russian or US kits.

Comment: Astronauts tend not to spend a lot of time tanning on the upper deck wearing a mylar speedo. Nothing exposed directly to the sun -> no sunscreen needed.

Comment: @paul oh, the image...

Comment: Related:https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31024/6944

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ultraviolet radiation does not get through the aluminum hull of the space station, so no such protection is needed for the crew inside. The glass of [EVA suits](http://history.nasa.gov/spacesuits.pdf) is made not to let UV light through, either. The same is true for the glass of the ISS' windows. So a random member of the ISS crew receives about as much UV radiation as you sitting inside writing this. Unless you use a CRT monitor, then they receive less.

The ionizing radiation the astronauts have to worry about is much shorter wave gamma radiation. And for that, there is no sunblock.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the CRT monitor that accompanied my first computer acquired way back in ... uh.. 1996/1997 or thereabouts has outlived 3 CPU replacements

Comment: Tanning studios are overrated ;)