# What are "applied moments of inertia" in the context of STS-61B's EASE/ACCESS?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, space-shuttle, eva, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5510/12102) links to https://history.nasa.gov/spacesuits.pdf which shows the image below. (fyi Wikipedia's [STS-61](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61) is not to be confused with [STS-61A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61A), [STS-61B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61-B) or [STS-61C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61-C), see answers to [Why so many STS-61's?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41400/12102)).

STS-61B saw the Experimental Assembly of Structures in EVA and the Assembly Concept for Construction of Erectable Space Structures, or  [EASE/ACCESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EASE/ACCESS). The results section of that article says:

> Applied moments of inertia during EVA were found to be on the order of 2.0 newton meters (1.5 lbf⋅ft). In neutral buoyancy simulation, the applied moments of inertia were around five times greater than those during EVA.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpvx.png) Assembly time during EVA was around 20% less than in neutral buoyancy simulation. The learning curve was on the order of 78%, and was unaffected by the strength, coordination, or size of the astronaut, or the fit of the space suit.[5] In both environments, moments of inertia were applied as short impulses, interspersed by several seconds of coasting.

While *torque* can have units of lbf⋅ft, the corresponding units of [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) would be lbf ft s².

So in the context of STS-61B's EASE/ACCESS, are "applied moments of inertia" really "astronaut-applied torques"? Or are they actually moments of inertia?

[image]

> Astronaut Sherwood C. Spring wears the EMU while checking joints on a tower extending from the Space Shuttle Atlantis cargo bay during mission STS 61 -B. He is standing on the end of the arm of the remote manipulator system connected to the space shuttle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the author of the Wikipedia article made an error.

The [source document](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11541162-moments-applied-in-the-manual-assembly-of-space-structures-ease-biomechanics-results-from-sts-61b/), an abstract of the paper *Moments Applied in the Manual Assembly of Space Structures: EASE Biomechanics Results From STS-61B* simply calls them "moments", not "moments of inertia".  Calling them "moments" is [OK](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54383) and basically equivalent to "torques".

> Moments applied in these manual handling tasks were calculated on the
>   basis of the reconstructed movements taking into account effects of
>   inertia, drag and virtual mass. Applied moments of 2.0 Nm were typical
>   for beam rotations in EVA. Corresponding applied moments in NBS were
>   typically up to five times greater. Moments were applied as impulses
>   separated by several seconds of coasting in both EVA and NBS.