# What do the RD numbers of Russian rocket engines mean?

Tags: engines, engine-design, terminology, russia

Most Russian rocket engines have a name on the form of for example [RD-107](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-107) (РД-107).

But apart from different engines having different numbers, how is the number chosen?

- All RD-2xx engines appears to be N2O2/UDMH and all RD-1xx engines appear to be LOX/RG-1, but that does not explain names like [RD-58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-58)
- They are not chronological: [RD-58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-58) is almost two decades older than [RD-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-8). Many numbers are also seemingly skipped.
- Similar numbers are not always similar engines: [RD-0120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-0120) is a LOX/LH2 engine, while [RD-120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-120) is a LOX/RG-1 engine.
- What's the occasional leading zero, like the nuclear [RD-0410](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-0410)?

Comment: I have encountered hundreds of logical, standardized naming/numbering systems in my life, and very few of them have survived as long as five years without being superseded and replaced by new, incompatible, logical standardized naming/numbering systems.

Comment: e.g. [Why so many STS-61's?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41400/12102)

Comment: Tim Dodd, the Everyday Astronaut has been working on a video entangling all the different engines, their naming, etc. for several weeks now. Going by what he has said in his recent live streams, an answer to your question will require about a month of research and be impossible to fit into Stack Exchange's 32000 character limit. The good thing is, he will mostly be quarantined in his hotel room for his stay at Boca Chica, so hopefully that video will answer your question soon. Until then, you will probably have to settle for "It's complicated".

Comment: That should read "untangling", of course :-D "Entangled" is what happens when you start researching this stuff, apparently.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-xyXDiC92s TL;DR: some numbers make sense, others don't